Select a single row based on conditions in multiple rows
I am working on a project related to arthropod species identification.
Here is a simplified table where we list various arthropod species with their properties:



i_spID
t_property
t_species
i_property_val




1
nmb_legs
Blatta germanica
6


1
nmb_wings
Blatta germanica
4


2
nmb_legs
Musca domestica
6


2
nmb_wings
Musca domestica
2


3
nmb_legs
Latrodectus hesperus
8



i_spID and t_property comprise the primary key.
Each species may have multiple properties (unlimited number) in the table. The ultimate goal is giving a set of properties to identify (ideally) a single species.
I have come up with a query having multiple subqueries, each for each pair of property/value:
SELECT t1.i_spID, t1.t_species
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM DBO.t_species
  WHERE t_property = 'nmb_legs'
  AND i_property_val = 6
) AS t1, (
  SELECT *
  FROM DBO.t_species
  WHERE t_property = 'nmb_wings'
  AND i_property_val = 4
) AS t2
WHERE t1.i_spID = t2.i_spID

(this one identifies the cocroach 'Blatta germanica')
The problem is that as the number of properties grows the query becomes too combersome especially the "where" part in which we need to connect each subquery with all the others through i_spID.
So is there a better way to write the query?
Create and fill in table SQL:
CREATE table DBO.t_species
 (
  i_spID                     int NOT NULL,
  t_property                 nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
  t_species                  nvarchar(50),
  i_property_val             int
 );

ALTER TABLE DBO.t_species
ADD CONSTRAINT pkID_sp01 PRIMARY KEY (i_spID,t_property);

INSERT INTO DBO.t_species (i_spID, t_property, t_species, i_property_val)
VALUES (1, 'nmb_legs', 'Blatta germanica', 6),
       (2, 'nmb_legs', 'Musca domestica', 6),
       (3, 'nmb_legs', 'Latrodectus hesperus', 8),
       (1, 'nmb_wings', 'Blatta germanica', 4),
       (2, 'nmb_wings', 'Musca domestica', 2)


MySQL is very very different to SQL Server, please correct your tags to be the single RDBMS you want your solution in.

I removed the mysql tag. The use of DBO indicates it's very likely that the OP is using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.

Please use proper JOIN.  It's been around for over 30 years!!!

Dale, Bill,
You are right, SS and MySql are quite different, but I use both and solutions for either of them bill be fine to me. And yes I've used SS in this thread.

This is task relation division with reminder.
I think it's better for you to separate the query parameters (name and attribute value) and the query itself.
See example
Here you can keep a list of parameters separately in the CTE without changing the main query.
Classical approach
with params as(
  select property_name,property_value 
  from (values 
     ('nmb_legs',6)
    ,('nmb_wings',4)
  )t(property_name,property_value )
)
SELECT distinct t_species
FROM t_species AS t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM params p
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT *
                FROM t_species t2
                 WHERE t2.i_spId=t1.i_spId
                   AND (t2.t_property = p.property_name)
                   AND (t2.i_property_val = p.property_value)
               )
    );

I suggest this option
with params as(
  select property_name,property_value 
  from (values 
     ('nmb_legs',6)
    ,('nmb_wings',4)
  -- other properties and values
  --  ,('nmb_eyes',1)
  )t(property_name,property_value )
)
select t.i_spId,max(t_species) t.t_species
from t_species t
inner join params p on p.property_name=t.t_property
  and p.property_value=t.i_property_val
group by i_spID
having count(*)=(select count(*) from params);




i_spId
t_species




1
Blatta germanica



Before grouping we have



i_spID
t_property
t_species
i_property_val
property_name
property_value




1
nmb_legs
Blatta germanica
6
nmb_legs
6


1
nmb_wings
Blatta germanica
4
nmb_wings
4


2
nmb_legs
Musca domestica
6
nmb_legs
6



fiddle
It would be more appropriate to pass a list of value parameters (property,value) as a query parameter.
In this example, the parameter is passed as the string
'property_name1=value1,property_name2=value2,property_name 3=value 3' 

We split this string into parts property_name=value using string_split. Then we also divide this pair into 2 parts and determine the name and value.
declare @prop_value_list varchar(max)='nmb_legs=6,nmb_wings=4';

with params as(
  select pv
    ,max(case when left(pv,len(nv))=nv then nv end)property_name
    ,max(case when left(pv,len(nv))=nv then null else nv end)property_value
  from(
     select v1.value pv ,v2.value nv
     from string_split(@prop_value_list,',') v1
     cross apply string_split(v1.value,'=') v2
    )a
  group by pv
)
select t.i_spId,max(t.t_species) t_species
from t_species t
inner join params p on p.property_name=t.t_property
  and p.property_value=t.i_property_val
group by i_spID
having count(*)=(select count(*) from params);

CTE params output is



pv
property_name
property_value




nmb_legs=6
nmb_legs
6


nmb_wings=4
nmb_wings
4



Example with parameter as XML
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = 
'<PropertiesList>
      <Property>
          <property_name>nmb_legs</property_name>
          <property_value>6</property_value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
          <property_name>nmb_wings</property_name>
          <property_value>4</property_value>
      </Property>
</PropertiesList>'
;

with params as(
SELECT 
    b.value('(./property_name/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as [property_name]
  , b.value('(./property_value/text())[1]','int') as [property_value]
FROM @xml.nodes('/PropertiesList/Property') as a(b)
)
select t.i_spId,max(t.t_species) t_species
from t_species t
inner join params p on p.property_name=t.t_property
  and p.property_value=t.i_property_val
group by i_spID
having count(*)=(select count(*) from params);

fiddle
See also tutorials
and here

Hi ValNik,
All your versions work perfectly!
I like most the one with passing the value list as a query parameter.
Thank you,
Alex

Group by t_species and count the number of matches. You can then add all the criteria you want and accept only the results that have a match count equal to the number of criteria checked.
SELECT t_species, COUNT(*) as MatchCount
FROM DBO.t_species     
WHERE (t_property='nmb_legs'  AND i_property_val=6)  
      OR
      (t_property='nmb_wings' AND i_property_val=4)
GROUP BY t_species
HAVING COUNT(*)=2

fiddle



t_species
MatchCount




Blatta germanica
2




Hi Bart,
great! - short and sweet!

Another method is combining the props and values together per species, using string_agg and then filter using simple like operators
select t.i_spID,
       t.species 
from   ( SELECT s.i_spID, 
                min(t_species) as species,
                (SELECT STRING_AGG (s.t_property + '_' + convert(varchar(10), i_property_val), ',')
                ) AS props
         FROM   DBO.t_species s
         group by s.i_spID
       ) t 
where  t.props like '%nmb_legs_6%'
and    t.props like '%nmb_wings_4%'

dbFiddle here
result



i_spId
species




1
Blatta germanica



The advantage is this method is that you can always easily put all your filtering at the bottom of the query in simple where statements which makes it easy to pass them as parameters for example
The trick of this method is that all the properties and values are combined per species in the group by, it looks like this



i_spID
species
props




1
Blatta germanica
nmb_legs_6,nmb_wings_4


2
Musca domestica
nmb_legs_6,nmb_wings_2


3
Latrodectus hesperus
nmb_legs_8



and now you have only one row per species with all the props and vales, which makes it easier to search

Very interesting solution GuidoG!

@cadol_askUbu Thank you, I like to keep things as simple as possible and keep performance in mind. There's a dbFiddle in the answer, so you can test it out with other values if you want, so you can see that it actually also works as expected

Yes GuidoG, I've tried it and it works just fine
